# Android Tabs: content from the second tab gets hidden under content from the first tab

Tags: android, view, tabs

I'm trying to create an App that has a 2-tabbed activity, where tab1 has a picture and some text on top of it, and tab2 has two buttons users could click on (that should lead to further activities)

For some reason, I couldn't get the buttons on tab2 to show; all I can see is the same picture from tab1. On closer inspection, I noticed that the buttons are hidden under the picture from tab1. What am I doing wrong? How do I make that picture go away and not show up on tab2?

The following is my code:

IndexActivity

```
public class IndexActivity extends TabActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1content);
    spec.setIndicator("tab1");
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2content);
    spec.setIndicator("tab2");
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);    

    }
}
```

My main.xml file goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="5dp">
           <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
           <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">       
                <include layout="@layout/tab1"/>
                <include layout="@layout/tab2"/>            
           </FrameLayout>           
 </LinearLayout>
```

tab1.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:scaleType="center"
                  android:src="@drawable/pic"/>
       <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrolltab1"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <TextView  android:id="@+id/tab1content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:background="#65000000"
                  android:text="@string/text"
          android:textColor="#ffffffff"
          android:textSize="20sp"
              android:padding="15dp"  
        />
       </ScrollView>      
</merge>
```

tab2 is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab2content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.10"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.10"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help! I must've overlooked something but I can't figure out what:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following two lines from the `FrameLayout` in your `main.xml` and see what happens.

```
<include layout="@layout/tab1"/>
<include layout="@layout/tab2"/>
```

Comment: But did you try it to see what happened? The reason is that you are adding views multiple times. The layouts from `tab1.xml` and `tab2.xml` are being added automatically when you call `setContentView(R.layout.main)` but then you are creating `TabSpecs` the first of which contains the `TextView` (tab1content) from `tab1.xml` and the second contains the whole layout from `tab2.xml` (tab2content). When you call `spec.setContent(...)` you are manually repeating inflations of the layout file contents that `setContentView(R.layout.main)` has already done because of <include> elements in `main.xml`.

Comment: I took out the include files and the app won't start at all (forced close); strangely I seem to have the fix the problem by changing android:src to android:background. But what you made makes a lot of sense...does that mean I actually have 4 tabs even though I'm only seeing two? I don't know what I'm doing anymore:(

Comment: No - you have two tabs but I think you're adding in some of the tab content twice to each tab. You don't need anything in your `FrameLayou` unless you want it to appear in every tab. One thing I don't understand is using `<merge...>` in the tab1.xml why isn't it just a standard `LinearLayout`? I also don't understand why removing the `<include>` elements would cause force close - as I said you don't need anything in the `FrameLayout` in the XML file - trace the exception which is causing it.

Comment: I don't even know what I did, but I got everything working now! I'm using the <merge> element following this guide...http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html I still have my <include> elements but I'll try to take them out again and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

i sugggest you have a look at this....

you example actually fairly represent this example.... [android tabhost tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1)

I hope you have seen it already.... this was the one i used when i frist developed my first android tab widget...

PS: Do have a look at this example [part 2](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-%E2%80%93-part-2) of the above ... continuation each and everything you need to know.

Comment: did it solve your problem... if yes would you mind indicating my answer as the answer to your problem.. if no... can you please tell me what you have tried,

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and your XML I think the problem is with the tab1.xml with this line:

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/tab1content"...
```

Try to put a layout around the `ImageView` and `ScrollView`. And move the `android:id="@+id/tab1content"` to the layout. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1content"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:scaleType="center"
              android:src="@drawable/pic"/>
       <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrolltab1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#65000000"
          android:text="@string/text"
          android:textColor="#ffffffff"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:padding="15dp" />
       </ScrollView>

   </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Comment: Hey the buttons do show up on tab2 now; however, the text "@string/text" in tab1 is no longer visible:(

Comment: Yeah that's a different problem with your layout, you should mark the answer in this thread and ask a new question for the new problem.

Comment: I probably did something else too, but I changed android:src to android:background that fixes my problem...